# Add % margins on a % div

Tags: css, mobile, center, percentage, margins

I'm having some bug on a website I'm designing and, about responsive design.

I want to create a box, with a 90% width of the screen for example, and then add 3 other boxes inside the main box, but centered horizontally with percentage margin because I want always centered on mobile versions of the website. Like this for example:

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {
 width: 90%;
 border: green;
}

li {
 margin-left: 11%;
 margin-right: 11%;
}
```

But when I resize the browser, the third "li" goes down and don't center all 3.
How I can do this? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont believe this
all of this is due the fact adding break lines or spaces in your code (while using display: inline-block) adds space between the elements.

instead of

```
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
```

try

```
<li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
```

Your should end with something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Margin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body, ul {margin: 0;  padding: 0;  width: 100%}
ul {background: green; list-style-type: none}
li {display: inline-block; width: 11%; margin:0 11%; background: red}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li> <!-- No break lines nor spaces -->
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```